# Печать русских символов в pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Я пытался печатать через pyautogui но увы он поддерживает только английские буквы.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.write("Парам, пам, пам", interval=0.1)
```

Но текст так и не получается написать, я пытался менять раскладку (Привет - Ghbdtn) но это работает очень не стабильно, например если запустить скрипт с русской раскладкой то он вообще не будет писать, для этого нужно включать при запуске английскую раскладку а после запуска делать паузу и переключать на русскую, не удобно это.

Искал в интернете как сделать "Человеческую" Печать с интервалами между каждой буквой, ничего найти так и не смог.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Какой-то странный модуль `pyautogui`. Куда не посмотри, не работает и требует костылей.

Ваш вопрос можно решить через буфер обмена. Следующий код может напечатать любой текст. При этом сохраняя значение буфера на случай, если он был пользовательским.

```
import pyautogui, pyperclip, keyboard

def paste(text: str):    
    buffer = pyperclip.paste()
    pyperclip.copy(text)
    keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl + v')
    pyperclip.copy(buffer)


pyautogui.hotkey('Win')
paste("Привет мир!")
```

У меня не срабатывает эмуляция нажатия клавиш

```
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
```

Поэтому используется модуль клавиатуры

```
# Для установки pip install keyboard
keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl + v')
```

## Обновление

Вариант написания текста с задержкой, т.е. эмуляция печати текста

```
from keyboard import press_and_release
from time import sleep
import pyautogui, pyperclip

def paste(text: str):    
    pyperclip.copy(text)
    press_and_release('ctrl + v')


def type(text: str, interval=0.0):    
    buffer = pyperclip.paste()
    if not interval:
        paste(text)
    else:
        for char in text:
            paste(char)
            sleep(interval)
    pyperclip.copy(buffer)


pyautogui.hotkey('Win')
type('Привет мир!', 0.1)
```

Comment: а запускаете от администратора ?

Comment: @Интик VS Code работает от администратора, по-другому не запускал

Comment: Не вижу смысла: type("Привет мир!"). Если он берёт текст из буфера, и мне нужно именно напечатать как человек с интервалами между каждой буквой, а не тупо ctrl + c и ctrl + v

Comment: @userpy вы этого не сказали в вопросе и не использовали там интервал

Comment: @Viewed прошу прощение, исправил

Comment: @userpy добавил